# PHP script of WP plugin takes 11 seconds to load

Tags: php, performance, wordpress, pingdom

I'm no .php expert, so I'm looking for a little help (or at least an explanation)

A plugin I'm using on my organization's site (called Coin Slider 4 WordPress) is slowing the site to a crawl. I ran a full page test on pingdom tools and the plugin's .php file (coin-slider-4-wp.css.php) takes more than **11 seconds** to load. The .php file itself is only 1kb, and nothing else is particularly slow.

Here's a screen shot: [image: Screenshot]

And here's the text of the .php file in question:

```
/*  Coin Slider jQuery plugin CSS styles
    http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider
*/

.coin-slider { overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; position: relative; }
.coin-slider a{ text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none; }

.cs-buttons { font-size: 0px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.cs-buttons a { margin-left: 5px; height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; color: #B8C4CF; text-indent: -1000px; }
.cs-active { background-color: #B8C4CF; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-title { width: 920px; padding: 10px; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-prev,  .cs-next { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px 10px; }

#coin-slider-coin-slider { width: 940px}
```

Not really sure what's going on, but any tips/advice would be great, as this is obviously making our site unusable :/ 
Thanks!

Comment: And what code does said .php file contain?

Comment: hey @mario the .php file is pasted above in the quote. Sorry... it's too long to post in the reply.

Comment: Which is why you have an [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14244574/edit) beneath your question. If it is a static `.css` file as posted above, then remove the `.php` extension and adapt its resource links. No need to pipe it through PHP; albeit that wouldn't explain a 11 sec delay.

Comment: Hey mario, I couldn't edit because stackoverflow said Karl's edit was more substantive.
Yeah... I was wondering why it was a .css.php file. But I'm still not sure why that would cause an 11 second delay...
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

The coin slider 4 WP plugin hasn't been updated in 2 years. I'd recommend adopting something more stable and actively maintained such as [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/features/#wordpress)

**UPDATE**: You could also tell the plugin not to call that php file.

Open the Editor in WP in your Plugins sidebar. On the right you will see a drop down with the different plugins you can edit. Slect the coinslider plugin. Now below that dropdown, you will see a list of files. In your **coinslider-content.php** file, there is a link to your CSS file.

Remove this line:

```
<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".$path."css/coin-slider-4-wp.css.php\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" charset=\"utf-8\"/>
```

From:

```
function cs_head(){

    $path =  get_bloginfo('wpurl')."/wp-content/plugins/coin-slider-4-wp/";

    $script = "
        <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".$path."css/coin-slider-4-wp.css.php\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" charset=\"utf-8\"/>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"".$path."scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js\"></script>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"".$path."scripts/coin-slider.min.js\"></script>
        ";

    echo $script;
}
```

Once you have removed that line, copy the content from your **coin-slider-4-wp.css.php** file. Click Editor on you Theme sidebar on the left. On the right you will see a list of files, one of them being **style.css**. Paste the contents of your **coin-slider-wp.css.php** at the bottom of your **style.css (stylesheet)** file.

Once you have done all this. It should remove that 11s it takes to request the file. Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Yeah, I've used Nivo Slider on other sites with better results. I'm just asking people smarter than me if there's a way I can salvage this plugin, so I don't have to re-train people how to insert a new slider. =)

Comment: Try running Firebug to see what shows up. Maybe there is an error being cause by the javascript. I understand where you are coming from. But in the future, you will be glad you changed the slider to begin with. Good luck @user1964359!

Comment: the Firebug shows similar results to the pingdom above. Anyways, here's the link: http://s7.postimage.org/6ya6t058q/Screen_Shot_2013_01_09_at_5_27_13_PM.jpg

Comment: @user1964359 I have updated my answer to give you a fix for your problem. Try it out and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Karl, I'll try that now and post back. (It may take awhile, as even the backend is now crawling)

Comment: Hey @karl, I copied the contents of coin-slider-wp.css.php and pasted it at the bottom of my theme's stle.css file. 

I then deleted the "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"".$path."css/coin-slider-4-wp.css.php\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen\" charset=\"utf-8\"/>" line from coinslider-content.php.

Looks like the coin-slider-wp.css.php file is still being called and it's still taking forever to load. Here's a screenshot from GTMetrix: http://s7.postimage.org/u7eqg0vbf/gtmetrix.png

Comment: @user1964359 There must be some caching happening. If you have a plugin that is caching your site, clear it. Also, make sure to completely log out of your WP panel and close your browser. Open it up and visit your page again. Let me know if it is still happening.